# Does this sentence "How long does it take you to watch TV" make any sense?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence-meaning

We often say "**How long does it take you to travel from Melbourne to Sydney by train?**", we know the beginning & the end.

But what if we say "**How long does it take you to watch TV?**". It doesn't have the beginning & the end.

Also, can we say:

**How long does it take you to wash dishes?**

**How long does it take you to play chess?**...

I knew 1 textbook say "**How long does it take you to cook dinner?**"

So, do you native often say "**How long does it take you to watch TV?**"

Note:

I have not problem with dummy "it". That was the typo error. My problem is that can we use that structure for phrases like "wash dishes", "play chess", "watch TV", etc which don't have a clear beginning & the end as "go from 1 place to another"

Comment: It is not clear what you want to know, Tom.   Do you want to know how long someone watches TV?  "How long *does it take*" refers to something with a finite duration.  Watching TV is an activity of variable duration.

Comment: Does this sentence “How long does it take you to watch TV” make any sense? Or do native say it? This is what I want to know?

Comment: No, it makes no sense, for the reason I gave.

Comment: @TRomano, but in textboox, it says "How long does it you to cook dinner?"

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense.  This would be semantically similar to asking someone "How long does it take you to breathe?", "How long does it take you to wear underwear?"

Comment: Dinner is, at some point, cooked and ready to eat. The time required may vary, but it is not an activity that can go on indefinitely. You are not asking a question about English. You are asking a question about the difference between watching TV and cooking dinner, and if you cannot understand that difference, you might as well sit in front of the TV.

Comment: @TRomano, but it uses simple present tense & thus it could mean "the **average** amount of time you spend on TV ", similar to "how many hours do you sleep a day"-->someday you sleep longer & some day shorter but it means an average  sleeping period.

Comment: No, Tom, it cannot mean that. You are thinking of the not quite idiomatic "How long do *you* take watching TV?" In your question you use so-called "dummy it": "How long does *it* take you to watch TV?"  That question, with "it", means "How much time is required for you *to complete the task*?"

Comment: How much time do *you* spend watching TV each day, on average?  How long does *it* take you to tie your shoelaces?

Comment: To be clear, when you wrote "How long does it you to cook dinner?" (apparently from a textbook), did you actually mean to type "How long does it **take** you to cook dinner?" Without the "*take*" the sentence isn't structurally valid (and all your other sentences include "take" correctly).

Comment: A valid question in this form would be "how long does it take you to get bored with watching television?".

Answer (score 1):

The structure "*How long does it take [for you] to....?*" implies a task with some start state and finished state. The question asks about the time required to move from the beginning state to the end state.

How long does it take [you] to...

- wash the dishes?

  - Start: pile of dirty dishes
  - Finished: clean dishes
- cook dinner?

  - Start: raw ingredients
  - Finished: a meal, ready to eat
- play chess?

  - Start: chess pieces in initial start position
  - Finished: one player in checkmate (or stalemate)
- travel from Melbourne to Sydney?

  - Start: you're in Melbourne
  - Finished: you're in Sydney

In these cases, we have different states, and it take some amount of time to move between them. For some people (or for some modes of transportation, or different cities), the task may take a short time, and for others it may take a long time.

In the case of watching TV, this question doesn't make sense because the "amount of time it takes to watch TV" is always the amount of time you choose to spend watching TV.

- Start: you're not watching TV yet
- Finished: you have watched TV for [X] hours -- obviously this "takes" as many hours as you just spent watching T.V.

It can't take someone more or less than an hour to watch an hour of television (versus cooking: it can take someone viable time to make a meal).

If you want to ask how long someone spends watching TV, ask one of these questions:

> How long do you spend watching TV each day?
>
> How much TV do you watch each day?

Comment: I find that playing chess (or in my case Go) is unlike the task-related activities. Any given game may be of unknown duration; even when playing with a clock the time schemes often allow for over-time. More likely, one just goes to a club (possibly online) and plays a few games, and maybe watches a few more. It's much closer to watching TV in terms of time used.

Comment: @djna That's a fair point. While it fits the model of start-to-finish state, I agree that it's not feasible to answer "how long?" it takes to play a game, since (1) could vary hugely from game to game and (2) it's not really a "task" but a recreational activity done for as long as it's pleasant.

Comment: @djna Maybe if you said "How long does it take you to a *single complete game* of chess?" it would fit a little better, but still awkward per my point #1. I'm working on an edit.

Comment: @djna I believe this is a case where the question doesn't account for unusually complex circumstances.  For instance, it might be difficult to answer "How long does it take to wash the dishes" if sometimes it's as simple as tossing out a pizza box and sometimes it's scouring a baked-on casserole from a pan.   The point that apsillers made about the difference between a task with a set finish and a task that is open-ended is still a good one.

Comment: @Mike Kozar, yes I very much agree that apsillers' answer is good, and very helpful. I just wanted to point out that chess is not quite a simple a task-focused activity as it might appear.

Comment: @apsillers This question revolves around the questioner's confusion about the "dummy it." See TRomano's comments above and also [this](http://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22dummy+it%22).

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm familiar with the "dummy it" expletive pronoun. It's not obvious to me that that's causing the OP's confusion. (On the other hand, I don't see any evidence that it's *not* what's causing the confusion, but could you point to a particular sentence or phrase in the question or comments that suggests the question hinges on expletives?) In particular, TRomana's comment about dummy-it (while certainly not *wrong*) appeared to me to be a non sequitur based on the preceding conversation.

Comment: @apsillers - I don't doubt you're aware of the ubiquitous _it!_ The link was for readers. In back and forth above with TRomano, OP seems to tell us that he confuses "how long does it take you" with "how long do you take." This makes me think that the dummy it is where he comes a cropper. I could be wrong, though. My daughter told me that I was wrong in April!

Comment: The start to finish concept is good way of explaining what's wrong with the watching TV situation. The variability problem of the chess game and the washing up can be eliminated by adding the magic words "on average". How long does it take [on average] for you to play [a game of] chess?

Comment: @apsillers On further reading, _revolves around_ is too strong. _Partakes of?_ In any case I see why TRomano raised it. The OP introduced it in his examples, and seems to be parsing _it take(s) you_ as some kind of phrasal.

Comment: I'm not even sure that "on average" works for a game of chess or Go. Tournament games have specified time-limits which may range from classic (hours) through rapid (10s of minutes) to blitz (less than 10 minutes), so it's not so much **my** average that matters, it's the rules of the tournament of the day. It is reasonable to ask me for my preferred time limit; I like to play Go with time limits that complete the game in less than an hour.

Comment: I have not problem with dummy "it". That was the typo error. My problem is that can we use that structure for phrases like "wash dishes", "play chess", etc which don't have a clear beginning & the end as go from 1 place to another

Answer (score 0):

"play chess" or "watch TV" are not fixed activities, so it doesn't make sense to ask "how long does it take you". I play chess as long as I like, which can be very short or very long". You could ask "how long does it take to play a chess party", and I could answer "if you play according to international tournament rules, it could take six hours", but "how long does it take to play chess" has no sensible answer.

On the other hand, "how long does it take to play chess well" asks how much time you need to change from an absolute beginner to someone who plays chess well, so you can give an answer there.